How do i get this binary option line chart trading widget
enter image description here
please anybody have an idea of how i can get this type of widget, i have checked trading view and some other platform, but have not been able to find it, source_line-> https://videforex.com/trading/option/EUR-USD_OTC  please if there's any where you can recommend me to get it i will be much grateful thank you.
tried getting this widget from trading view, but discovered they do not offer something like this.
